# Jmeter interactions with UI and Database inserts simultaneosly

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2

When we create a Jmeter script through Blazemeter/third party script recorder and there are some insert/update and delete functions on UI involve in records. Just want to know when we run same JMeter script with 100 users, Do those new records get inserted/update/delete in database as well ? If yes, then what should be remaining 99 users data if there are unifications on UI.

Answer (score 0):

When you record the user action it results into [hard-coded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) values so if you add `foo` line in the UI it gets added to the database.

When you replay the test with 1 user depending on your application implementation

- either another `foo` line will get added to the database
- or you will get an error regarding this entry is present already

When you run the same test with 100 users the result will be the same, to wit:

- either you will have 100 identical new/updated entries
- or you will have 100 errors

So I would suggest doing some [parameterization](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) of your tests so each thread (virtual user) would operate its own unique data, like:

- have a CSV file with credentials for 100 users which can be read using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- when you add an entry you can also consider adding an unique prefix or postfix to this like:

  - current virtual user number via [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)
  - current iteration via `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars)
  - current timestamp via [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)
  - unique GUID-like structure via [__UUID() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID)
  - etc.